# C# Distinct in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, distinct

I've got the problem after changing some code. My idea is like this: I am counting the number of words in document, but just 1 copy of a word for each document, for example:

> Document 1 = Smith Smith Smith Smith => Smith x1
>
> Document 2 = Smith Alan Alan => Smith x1, Alan x1
>
> Document 3 = John John => John x1

but the total count of smiths should:

> Smith x2 (in 2 documents out of 3), Alan x1 (1 out of 3 documents), John x1 (1 out of 3 documents)

I think it was working before when I had a separate method for distinct (counting also all the words if `distinct = false`), now it produces just `1`.

The code before:

```
    private Dictionary<string, int> tempDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    private void Splitter(string[] file)
    {              
            tempDict = file
                .SelectMany(i => File.ReadAllLines(i)
                .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))                    
                .AsParallel()
                .Select(word => word.ToLower()) 
                .Distinct())
                .GroupBy(word => word)                    
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
    }
```

It should be changed so it returns dictionary, but in the proces of making app changed this to this code:

```
private Dictionary<string, int> Splitter(string[] file, bool distinct, bool pairs)
{
    var query = file
        .SelectMany(i => File.ReadLines(i)
        .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(word => word.ToLower())
        .Where(word => !word.All(char.IsDigit)));
    if (distinct)
    {
        query = query.Distinct();
    }
    if (pairs)
    {
        var pairWise = query.Pairwise((first, second) => string.Format("{0} {1}", first, second));

        return query
                .Concat(pairWise)
                .GroupBy(word => word)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
    }
    return query
        .GroupBy(word => word)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());           
}
```

Also note that `query = file.Distinct();` returns just name of the document. SO it has to be something different.

@edit
This is how I am calling this method:

```
  private void EnterDocument(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> myFile= new List<string>();
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames)
            {
                myFile.Add(filename);

            }
        }
        string[] myFiles= myFile.ToArray();
        myDatabase = Splitter(myFiles, true, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Distinct()` will remove duplicates from your `IEnumerable` so calling it before the following...

```
return query
    .GroupBy(word => word)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

...will result in a list of all the unique words but with a count of 1.

**Edit:**

To solve the merging all lines issue you could do something like this:

```
List<string> allFilesWords = new List<string>();
foreach (var filename in file)
{
    var fileQuery = File.ReadLines(filename)
        .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(word => word.ToLower())
        .Where(word => !word.All(char.IsDigit)));
    allFilesWords.AddRange(fileQuery.Distinct());
}
return allFilesWords
        .GroupBy(word => word)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: So how can I count the real number in how many files this word is included? I have made an edit to how I am calling this.

Comment: Create a set of distinct words per file then merge all the sets together and group by as before to get overall words usage. The problem with your current code is that you're merging all the lines from all the files up front with the `SelectMany(i => File.ReadLines(i))`. At that point the knowledge of which line belongs to what file is removed.

Comment: I though that it was file based not ALL_FILES_AT_ONCE.. strange.

Comment: Remember that each statement results in a single `IEnumerable` result before being passed to the next LINQ function. `SelectMany()` merges `IEnumerable` collection results into a single `IEnumerable` set. In this case `File.ReadLines(i)` is the `IEnumerable` result being merged with all the other files `File.ReadLines()` results. If you were to call `Select(i => File.Readlines(i))` your result set would be `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`, without file association directly but each `iEnumerable<string>` would be the content of a file.

Comment: Sure but you say merge words per file, but how can I do this if it automagically merges all of them at once?

Comment: See my edit. Not written for a `Parallel.foreach` but you could easily do so. I've also only tackled the `Distinct()` case rather than pairing as well.